# LINQ query - needs to change a field name

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
private bool DescriptionValid(Membership membership, string identifier)
{
var query =
    from ms in new []
    {
        membership.premium.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
        membership.club.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
        membership.basic.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
        membership.junior.Select(m => new { m.Id, m.Remarks }),
    }
    let ev = ms.Where(x => x.Id == identifier).SingleOrDefault()
    where ev != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ev.Remarks)
    select ev;

return !query.Any();
```

}

I am look to see if Remarks is null or empty in at least one place.
My problem is that for membership.basic the remarks are actually in another field called description.

When I change m.remarks to m.description in my code, of course, the code breaks down. Can anyone tell me if I can include m.description and alias it in some way to have minimal impact on my code?

Comment: You can do `membership.basic.Select(m => new { m.Id, Remarks = m.Description }),`

Comment: argh! i had m.Remarks = m.Description
perfect. thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you only need to change

```
membership.basic.Select(m => new { m.Id, Remarks = m.Description })
```

Comment: @dstewart101, as this helped, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: had to come back to it, because stackoverflow wouldn't let me mark an answer until after 10 mins